# How can I ignore the difference between upper and lower case when searching with mysql

Tags: mysql

How can I ignore the difference between upper and lower case when searching with mysql

Answer (score 27):

Do something like this:

```
SELECT user 
FROM users 
WHERE UPPER( user ) = UPPER( 'moustafa' );
```

Basically you're converting your result to one case and comparing against the search term which is also converted to upper case, effectively ignoring case.

Comment: +1: Driving both sides of the evaluation to the same case (UPPER or LOWER) will provide case insensitive searching.  Caveat: Use of a function on the column will not use an index if one exists.

Answer (score 18):

The `UPPER` and `LOWER` functions can be used, but you can also affect the case-sensitivity by selecting the appropriate collation and/or column type.

For example, `latin1_general_cs` is case-sensitive with both `VARCHAR` and `VARBINARY`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `case_sensitive`;
CREATE TABLE `case_sensitive` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nonbinary` VARCHAR(255),
    `binary`  VARBINARY(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB COLLATE latin1_general_cs;

INSERT INTO `case_sensitive` (`nonbinary`, `binary`) VALUES ('A', 'A');

SELECT * FROM `case_sensitive` WHERE `nonbinary` = 'A';

+----+-----------+--------+
| id | nonbinary | binary |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | A         | A      |
+----+-----------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM `case_sensitive` WHERE `binary` = 'A';

+----+-----------+--------+
| id | nonbinary | binary |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | A         | A      |
+----+-----------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM `case_sensitive` WHERE `nonbinary` = 'a';

Empty set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM `case_sensitive` WHERE `binary` = 'a';

Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Whereas `latin1_general_ci` is case-insensitive with `VARCHAR`, and case-sensitive with `VARBINARY`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `case_insensitive`;
CREATE TABLE `case_insensitive` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nonbinary` VARCHAR(255),
    `binary`  VARBINARY(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB COLLATE latin1_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `case_insensitive` (`nonbinary`, `binary`) VALUES ('A', 'A');

SELECT * FROM `case_insensitive` WHERE `nonbinary` = 'A';

+----+-----------+--------+
| id | nonbinary | binary |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | A         | A      |
+----+-----------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM `case_insensitive` WHERE `binary` = 'A';

+----+-----------+--------+
| id | nonbinary | binary |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | A         | A      |
+----+-----------+--------+

SELECT * FROM `case_insensitive` WHERE `nonbinary` = 'a';

+----+-----------+--------+
| id | nonbinary | binary |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | A         | A      |
+----+-----------+--------+

SELECT * FROM `case_insensitive` WHERE `binary` = 'a';

Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

You should therefore pick a collation and column type that is most suited to your needs.  You can find more information here:

Case Sensitivity in String Searches
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case-sensitivity.html

Character Sets and Collations in MySQL
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-mysql.html

Character Sets and Collations That MySQL Supports
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-charsets.html

Answer (score 6):

Generally, you should use WHERE UPPER(COLUMNNAME) = UPPER('valuetocompare').

Alternatively, you culd use WHERE UPPER(COLUMNNAME) like UPPER('%valuetocompare%') if you want to do a substring search

Answer (score 2):

i use utf8_unicode_(CI)-case-insensitive collate on the column your searching....and it works

Answer (score 1):

you can store the data in the mySQL in lower case and just perform query on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name1 LIKE '%A%' OR column_name1 LIKE '%a%';
```

Comment: Only copy-pasting code is not enough, you have to explain what it does and how.