# Searching MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to search MySQL database with a search key entered by the user. My data contain upper case and lower case. My question is how to make my search function not case sensitive. ex:data in mysql is BOOK but if the user enters book in search input. The result is not found....Thanks..

My search code

```
$searchKey=$_POST['searchKey'];
$searchKey=mysql_real_escape_string($searchKey);

$result=mysql_query("SELECT *
            FROM product
            WHERE product_name like '%$searchKey%' ORDER BY product_id
                            ",$connection);
```

Comment: well..Thanks guys. All of you provide the correct answer. +1 to all and accepted answer for despart since he is the first one reply.Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just uppercase the search string and compare it to the uppercase field.

```
$searchKey= strtoupper($_POST['searchKey']);
$searchKey=mysql_real_escape_string($searchKey);

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product
        WHERE UPPER(product_name) like '%$searchKey%' ORDER BY product_id
         ",$connection);
```

Answer (score 2):

If possible, you should avoid using `UPPER` as a solution to this problem, as it incurs both the overhead of converting the value in each row to upper case, and the overhead of MySQL being unable to use any index that might be on that column.

If your data does not need to be stored in case-sensitive columns, then you should select the appropriate collation for the table or column.  See my answer to [how i can ignore the difference upper and lower case in search with mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150798/how-i-can-ignore-the-difference-upper-and-lower-case-in-search-with-mysql) for an example of how collation affects case sensitivity.

The following shows the `EXPLAIN SELECT` results from two queries.  One uses `UPPER`, one doesn't:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_a`;
CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  INDEX `value` (`value`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO table_a (value) VALUES
('AAA'), ('BBB'), ('CCC'), ('DDD'),
('aaa'), ('bbb'), ('ccc'), ('ddd');

EXPLAIN SELECT id, value FROM table_a WHERE UPPER(value) = 'AAA';
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table_a | index | NULL          | value | 258     | NULL |    8 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+

EXPLAIN SELECT id, value FROM table_a WHERE value = 'AAA';
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table_a | ref  | value         | value | 258     | const |    2 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
```

Notice that the first `SELECT` which uses `UPPER` has to scan all the rows, whereas the second only needs to scan two - the two that match.  On a table this size, the difference is obviously imperceptible, but with a large table, a full table scan can seriously impact the speed of your query.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy way to do it:

```
$searchKey=strtoupper($searchKey);

SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE UPPER(product_name) like '%$searchKey%' ORDER BY product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to avoid using `*` as much as possible. It is generally considered a bad idea. Select the columns using column names.

Now, your solution would be -

```
$searchKey=strtoupper($_POST['searchKey']);
$searchKey=mysql_real_escape_string($searchKey);

$result=mysql_query("SELECT product_name,
                            // your other columns
                    FROM product
                    WHERE UPPER(product_name) like '%$searchKey%' ORDER BY product_id
                        ",$connection);
```

**EDIT**

I will try to explain why it is a bad idea to use `*`. Suppose you need to change the schema of the product table(adding/deleting columns). Then, the columns that are being selected through this query will change, which may cause unintended side effects and will be hard to detect.

Comment: This wouldn't actually work, because you're still comparing the original data to upper case search criteria. Also, it's likely that the OP just excluded the list of `SELECT` columns to help focus the question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will get rid of * then

Comment: I stand corrected :) Also, glad to see you added `UPPER(product_name)` to the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html), case-sensitivity in searches depends on the collation used, and should be case-insensitive by default for non binary fields.

Make sure you have the field types and the query right (maybe there's an extra space or something). If that doesn't work, you can convert the string to upper case in PHP (ie: `$str = strtoupper($str)`) and do the same on the MySQL side (@despart)

EDIT: I posted the article above (^). AndI just tested it. Searches on CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT fields *are* case-insensitive (collation = latin1)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html check this article. :D

Comment: The case-sensitivity of CHAR, VARCHAR and TEXT fields depends on the collation of the table.  `latin1` is a character set, not a collation.  If the collation is not specified, it will usually default to a case-insensitive [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-server.html) like `latin1_swedish_ci`.  However, if you specified the `latin1_swedish_cs` collation, then CHAR, VARCHAR and TEXT would be case sensitive. See my answer for some more information.